# Is it possible to ignore Attributes in C#? Or disable the processing of them?

Tags: c#, android, attributes, xamarin, xamarin.android

In C# we can decorate methods with Attributes for numerous purposes.

E.g:

```
   [Activity (Label = "My Activity", MainLauncher = true)]
   public class MainActivity : Activity
```

This particular example is from Xamarin, it goes off and auto builds the Android Manifest file based on these attributes.

I want to know if there is any way to get the compiler to globally ignore these attributes? i.e Disable Attribute processing altogether.

My actual end goal is to manually generate my Android Manifest file myself but still keep these Attributes in the classes. I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a conditional compilation would do?

```
#if DEBUG
[Activity (Label = "My Activity", MainLauncher = true)]
#endif
public class MainActivity : Activity
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid making changes to the source files (they are part of a library I'll be consuming) but this will certainly do the trick. Thanks for the tip