# Choose startup activity to debug with xamarin android

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I have 2 activities, both marked as MainLauncher = true, which is desired behavior - I want to have 2 application shortcuts on device when installed.
During development I want to choose particular activity which will be always shown when I debug this application. I use Visual Studio 2015 update 3, latest Xamarin.Android

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity 1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/iconMain"]
...

[Activity(Label = "Activity 2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/iconMain"]
...
```

Comment: easiest: `MainLauncher = false`

Comment: But in this case I won't get 2 icons on device, that is also required during debug sessions. In fact, for production we'll deploy single icon. During debug and QA we need both, and I want to choose predictable activity while I start debug session to avoid extra interaction with device to launch application using different icon.

Comment: you're right, there should be a setting for that... you're looking for this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVgqg.png but i don't think is available in xamarin/vs

Answer (score 1):

You could use `#if` to show the second activity only in debug mode:

```
#if DEBUG
    [Activity(Label = "Activity 2", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/iconMain"]
#else
    [Activity(Label = "Activity 2", MainLauncher = false, Icon = "@drawable/iconMain"]
#end if
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want to achieve, but it is possible to build workaround based on such approach with multiple build configurations. I already use #if #else to shut down this activity in release build. What I want to have is to add both icons to device in all debug builds, but always run only 1 particular activity when I start debugging from Visual studio. Ideally I would like to find something like this in UI or some config files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVgqg.png

Comment: @dlxeon, I didn't find any UI or config file for it, Pilatus' suggestion is the workaround I could get, we often use the conditional code with the  #if directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162056/is-it-possible-to-ignore-attributes-in-c-or-disable-the-processing-of-them